# Lexical or preprocessor issue - Xcode 8.3.2 - Sierra 10.12.4

Tags: c++, xcode, header-files, podofo

This is have been truly cumbersome, and i've done a lot for research about it but ended up failing to solve it.

as you can see in the print-screen, this path entered in the Header Path Search and it contains all the .h files have been installed with PoDoFo including podofo-base.h as well as PdfVersion.h

However, I don't know why i'm getting this?

i read A LOT of solution with EL Captain but non of them worked with me as i have Sierra. also those solutions were for xCode 7 and earlier versions.

Please help!

[image: print-screen of the errors on Xcode]

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `/base` from the end of your header search path

Comment: crazy stuff showed up, like classified as "semantic issues" it is now 6 errors instead of 1 :(